# Where Next.js takes app code when client-side routing?

Tags: next.js

Let's say that I click a [Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) and forward myself to `/about` route. This `/about` route has only `getServerSideProps` and some simple JSX defined in it:

```
// /about page
import Head from 'next/head'
import Users from '../components/Users'

export default function About() {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>About Page</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Users /> // Some React Component that happens to be on this page

    </div>
  )
}

export async getServerSideProps = /* code that calls some API */
```

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-on-server-side):

> When you request this page on client-side page transitions through
> next/link (documentation) or next/router (documentation), Next.js
> sends an API request to the server, which runs getServerSideProps.
> **It’ll return JSON that contains the result of running getServerSideProps**

Which means that when I click the [Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) that leads to `/about` page, I will only get JSON with data for my page. But how do I get an actual code? I get the data, but how does the client get this part of my page:

```
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>About Page</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Users /> // Some React Component that happens to be on this page

    </div>
```

This JSX code is needed in order to render a page. From the docs I infer that it is not transfered to the client when using client-side routing. Then, where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

The doc part that you've added is correct only for the side of handling `getServerProps`.

The client side when navigating to other page, **firstly** loads the page js file, then it realizes that it has `getServerProps`, invoking it, when the data comes from the server, renders the page.

Comment: Which means that there are two round of requests. One to get .js page file and then parse it. And another to invoke getServerSideProps on the server and get its data. Right? Seems like not very optimal solution by Next.js

Comment: The page request is cached, so there are 2 requests only the **first** time you navigate at the **"client"** side, if the page is your first page, it will render it using ssr without this.